# How to do integration testing that needs OAuth access token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, linkedin-api

I have integration with Linkedin API and I have code like this. I want to test it and run it in CI/CD. To get access token I should open browser and allow my app to access my testing linkedin account. Also I can't put directly access token in the code because it can be expired. Refresh token has long expire but still it can be expire too. What's the best way to testing third party API like this?

```
await sendPostToLinkedIn({
  access_token: 'xxx',
  content: 'I got promoted today!'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is usual to only write CI / CD integration tests for your own code, rather than third party code. For your own APIs it is possible to use a technique of issuing your own mock JWT access tokens, then expose a mock JWKS URI for getting the token signing key, as in [these example integration tests of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.nodejs/blob/master/test/integrationTests.ts#L145). This avoids the need to deal with OAuth logins.

For a third party API where you have to run an authorization code flow, one option is to do that step manually, on an occasional basis, then run your test suite with the access token. After all, the third party API doesn't change when your own client code changes. Perhaps during CI / CD you could then mock the real API, and run the same tests, with a focus on testing your own client code.

It is possible to write your own [client code to run a code flow](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.tokenhandler.docker/blob/master/test/runHttpWorkflow.sh#L178), by following redirects and issuing form posts. But such code is complicated and a little fragile, so I would use it only sparingly.

Comment: I wish I can run integration test as it can be useful to check daily if the integration is broken or not especially when third party breaks the API

Comment: i'm having difficulties to grasp the mocking of user-rights. Do you have any good resources for this? For example, our api have 10 different roles which all can see different data. Now we have some extensive scripts that create accounts and test the api with those accounts but it seems like a real mess.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there are couple of different ways to solve this issue:

1. You can use some mock library which helps you create MockServer (for ex.
   WireMock C#). Then set up that mock servers with request and
   response. In your case the request would be the LinkedIn uri being
   used. You can set the mock response accordingly. In this way for each
   test case you can have separate setup and expectation. And you won't
   need token at all as you will be using the Mock server for LinkedIn
   not the original LinkedIn APIs.
2. And another not so good solution may be to have a Client registered
   with oauth ClientCredentials flow (with your identity provider). And use this client in your test
   cases. Since it's a Client Credential flow you won't require the
   user.